# Published Google Play Services but app still says "Ready to Publish"?

Tags: android

I have a game with Google play services. It said I had to publish Google Play services first to publish the game.So I made the Google Play services published but when I go to the game info side, it still says "Ready to Publish" but the buttons to publish aren't working or unavailable. When can I actually publish the app?

I have looked everywhere to publish it but I cannot find anything. Who can help me out here and let me know why it isn't actually live?

Answer (score 0):

HI there might be a delay from google dev console for few minutes, now i can see 'Publish' button active after publishing my game services and waited for atleast half hour,then i see publish button for app as well active